# How do i hide the interactive options in GGVIZ motion chart like selecting axis or size

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

I have made a motion chart for my project and i want to hide the interactive options provided like changing the axis or sizevar or colorvars.

```r
G3 = gvisMotionChart(data=x, 
                           idvar="Country", 
                           timevar="Year",
                           chartid="NAN",
                           xvar = "Av_BMI",
                           yvar = "Sugar",
                           colorvar = "Continent",
                           sizevar = "Population",options=list(width=1000, height=600))
```